# my code works but different from the answer? does it matter as long as its working? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript, I made a successful simple assignment (Calculator) and compared my code to the answer.... my code was not the same as the answer but it was working...

Is there "The" proper way to write the code? Is my code ok as long as it's functioning and went through the debugging with no issues?

My code:

```
let num1 = 8
let num2 = 2

document.getElementById("num1-el").textContent = num1
document.getElementById("num2-el").textContent = num2

function add(){
    var x = num1 + num2
    console.log(x)
    document.getElementById('sum-el').innerHTML= "Sum is:" + x
}

function sub(){
    var x = num1 - num2
    console.log(x)
    document.getElementById('sum-el').innerHTML= "Subtraction is:" + x
}

function multiply() {
    var x = num1 * num2
    console.log(x)
    document.getElementById('sum-el').innerHTML = "Multiplication is:" + x
}

function divide(){
    var x = num1 / num2
    console.log(x)
    document.getElementById('sum-el').innerHTML = "Division is:" + x
}
```

vs. the answer:

```
let num1 = 8
let num2 = 2
document.getElementById("num1-el").textContent = num1
document.getElementById("num2-el").textContent = num2

let sumEl = document.getElementById("sum-el")

function add() {
    let result = num1 + num2
    sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + result
}

function subtract() {
    let result = num1 - num2
    sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + result
}

function divide() {
    let result = num1 / num2
    sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + result
}

function multiply() {
    let result = num1 * num2
    sumEl.textContent = "Sum: " + result
}
```

Comment: You see how the "THE ANSWER" is less repetitive right

Comment: The answer is *better*, but yours isn't horrible, and if it works, then meh

Comment: Bear in mind that 2021 JS no longer uses `var`. You "can use it" (because JS never removes support for old language features, for good or for bad), but you shouldn't: use `let` for regular variables that you're going to change the value of, and use `const` for fixed values. Also don't use `.innerHTML` unless you're _actually_ setting HTML content. If not, use `.textContent` instead. And finally, modern JS has [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which you want instead of `+` ops for strings:  ```... = `Subtraction is: ${x}`;```

Comment: Thank You, I was looking for these explanations.

Answer (score 1):

It has some performance issues. When ever any one of the 4 functions `add`, `subtract`, `subtract`, `multiply` is executed, it always parses the DOM and find `document.getElementById('sum-el')` each time in your implementation.

Where as in the other scenario. the node that is obtained with `document.getElementById("sum-el")` has been stored in a local variable. So that when any one of the 4 function executes, it referes to that local variable. In this scenario DOM parsing happens only once. This provides a little bit more performace.

Comment: thank you, I was looking for such explanations!

Comment: @RamziOsta You are welcome. Please approve the answer if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, "does it matter as long as its working," doesn't have a black-and-white answer. Modern programming languages are complex enough that there are almost always multiple ways to accomplish the same task. The "best" way varies on context, resources, end-goal, the opinion of your boss, etc.

Gifted programmers are often intractable in their approach to programming. In their minds, "paths" are easily visible on how to do it.  They fail to understand that not all of us see things the way they do.  They can be very hard to deal with, and can be very critical of program code that works but that isn't done their way.

There are good ways, there are better ways, but there's no such thing as one right way.  At this stage in your learning, don't get hung up on which way is the best.  You'll be better served if you look at how others approached the task and try to understand why it works, how it could be improved, and what coding they used that would make your code better. Simply stated, don't code by your ego.  Code with curiosity and a desire to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is a lot cleaner, I often have to remind juniors to remove console outputs, which might not seem like a problem here, but it's a good habit to clean up what you wrote after you debug. I think the answer is also using a more OOP mindset by creating a reusable link to the DOM element. Lastly, I wouldn't use `var` in any scope anymore, I would only use const and let to define variables in JavaScript.